# how to display online each and every meta tags  in newline?

Tags: html, meta-tags

I want to display meta tags in newline means when i open a site and seeing the viewsource of the site the all meta tags is displayed in oneline.

i want to display each and every meta tag in one newline.

for ex:
 required output:

```
<meta name="description" content="vvvv sdhgf dbngfsdj">
<meta name="keywords" content="dgd, sfdg, sdjgj">
```

but displayed output like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="vvvv sdhgf dbngfsdj"><meta name="keywords" content="dgd, sfdg, sdjgj">
```

Comment: Uh... just add a newline to the source code?

Comment: I think he's asking for a Firefox extension.

Comment: those meta tags we r put in aspx page, if i gave <br\> to each and every tag, it effects header banner.

Comment: which language you are using asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

The newlines (or lack thereof) in a webpage's source code come directly from the web server; you cannot modify them.

It would be possible to write a browser extension to insert newlines when you click View Source, butI don't think there are any existing extensions that do that.

However, you can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) to view an HTML page's DOM tree; it will do what you're looking for.  (In the HTML tab)

Answer (score 0):

Its too long time to answer!

But will be help full for future readers.

```
 this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\r\n"));
 this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(keywords);
 this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\r\n"));
 this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(description);
 this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\r\n"));
```

**NOTE:** *Above Code is for `asp.net webpage only`*